How to display query result nicely in beeline terminal
I wrote a query, for example, select * from table1 limit 5;.
As there was a lot of columns, the result showed like the image. So my question is, how can I show the result nicely?
enter image description here
Thanks for the help.

use some kind of UI or export in a csv

There is a permission to export the data. So, what kind of UI can I use?

hmm, in cloudera, you have hue, in hortonworks, they have UI. Which vendor are you using ?

no worries. I had hue, but the service was down few days ago. this is why I ask if there is other option to view the data nicely.

there must be some settings... but i am not aware of it
